# Resetting powershell session to default installation state

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am writing PowerShell modules for my team. When I test them in my machine they work fine but often there will be errors when I execute on other machines. This is mainly due to some required modules are not imported or some environment variables are not set. To make sure the modules work on all machines I want to test the modules by resetting my PowerShell to the default state when installed. Is there any way to reset it including all imported modules.

Comment: You could use a dedicated VM with a default Windows installation to test this, that you spin up on demand if necessary. Resetting to an earlier snapshot is a very fast operation for most VM technologies. Messing with your local configuration runs the risk of either breaking it, or still not being representative of what you're actually going for.

Comment: I thought of setting up a VM. But these modules require other project-specific application to be installed and the applications get frequent upgrades hence I was looking for a simple solution of resetting my PowerShell so I don't have to maintain a new environment.

Comment: If you're updating frequently and you have no process in place for easily getting the updates on machines, that's arguably something you want to invest in. Doubly so if you're actually running into problems with deployment, as you're doing now. This is the sort of thing a staging environment is for. You don't need a complete server park with a CI pipeline for that, but it does help to have a little more than only local dev machines. To be clear: I don't know of any way, easy or otherwise, to reset PowerShell to what it would be on a blank machine, and I wouldn't trust anything engineered.

Comment: Thanks, @JeroenMostert. Making changes to process is way above my pay scale I will figure out something with VM's